# What type of padding does python use for RSA module?

Tags: python, encryption, rsa, padding

I'm new to encryption with Python and am wondering which padding is the default one for its [RSA module](https://stuvel.eu/python-rsa-doc/index.html)?

I get the key and decrypt the data by:

```
import rsa

(pub, priv) = rsa.newkeys(512)
# receive the encrypted data here
data = rsa.decrypt(encrypt_data, priv)
```

And as far as I am concerned, the padding methods include: RSA_PKCS1_PADDING, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING, RSA_SSLV23_PADDING, RSA_NO_PADDING.

Comment: It's very likely that it is `RSA_PKCS1_PADDING`. Could you post a hexadecimal or base 64 encoded string that was encrypted with the RSA module? It's pretty easy to check (using RSA_NO_PADDING).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes  The encrypted data I got is "\xab\xe2B\xe0Bt(~T\xcd\x1d>iwd\x16<'\xff\t\xa5_|$m9\xdd\xed*ee\xc1\x924c%\xcdHg\xc1h\xb8\xc7&\xf7\xb7\xd2\x8a\xd1\x1c \xab\x7f\xe8L\x17\x05m\x9dDC\x10I\xab". The code I used can be found at https://stuvel.eu/python-rsa-doc/usage.html (section 5.3). How can I figure it out according to this output?

Comment: @ArtjomB.  Yes, I believe that is the module I'm looking into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [rsa module](https://github.com/sybrenstuvel/python-rsa) (currently v3.4) supports only PKCS#1 v1.5 padding for encryption (randomized type 2 padding) and signing.

In `rsa/__init__.py` you can see that `rsa.encrypt()` is actually `rsa.pkcs1.encrypt()` which internally uses `rsa.pkcs1._pad_for_encryption()` which is an implementation of the previously mentioned PKCS#1 v1.5 padding.

Please note that nowadays ([ref](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12688/13022)), this padding should not be used anymore. OAEP is recommended for encryption and PSS for signing, both from PKCS#1 v2.0. PyCrypto supports OAEP/PSS and PKCS#1 v1.5 paddings.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I want.